# Resize an image using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, width

I know this question has been answered many times. 
However, my code does not seem to work despite I literally got it from the internet. I probably do something wrong, but what exactly I could not figure out.

I put the following **JS code** inside the HTML `<head>` tag :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imwidth = $('#jspp').width(); 
  var imheight = $('#jspp').height(); 
  if (imwidth < imheight) {
   $('#jspp').width(100);
  } else {
   $('#jspp').height(100);
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="jspp" src="https://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
</body>
```

Does somebody have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing a ')' at the end of your jQuery. Check your console.log for errors.

Comment: Don't assume everything you copy straight from the internet is correct and valid :)

Comment: @MCMXCII thanks! I corrected it, but it still does not work

Comment: @FluffyKitten hahah, unless you're a beginner like me I guess

Comment: If it's still not working, make sure you are including jQuery. Have you got any errors in your console?

Comment: What exactly is not working - are you getting an error or is the image not resizing properly?

Comment: Perhaps better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/027q85w8/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imwidth = $('#jspp').width(); 
  var imheight = $('#jspp').height(); 

  if (imwidth < imheight) {
    $('#jspp').css('width', '100px');
  } else {
    $('#jspp').css('height', '100px');
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="jspp" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Two things were wrong in your code.

- Missing `)` at the end of `document.ready`
- Assigning of `100px` in width & height.

Hope this will help you.